# Is there any way to set the left and right margin of a console using Terminal sequences? the same way we can currently set Top and Bottom?

Tags: c#, command-line, console, ncurses, terminal-emulator

**some background,**

I'm the author of a C# console library called Konsole (link below).

https://github.com/goblinfactory/konsole

The primary feature of the library is to provide a simple DSL for creating scrollable console windows like so ...

[image]

This works really well on windows, but currently does not work on 'nix' because the `.NET Core` port of `Console` is incomplete. Yeah, it's incomplete Sobs! if you call `Console.MoveBufferArea(...)`, you'll receive a stern `PlatformNotSupported` rebuking, like so ...

```
Unhandled exception. System.PlatformNotSupportedException: Operation is not supported on this platform.
   at System.ConsolePal.MoveBufferArea(Int32 sourceLeft, Int32 sourceTop, Int32 sourceWidth, Int32 sourceHeight, Int32 targetLeft, Int32 targetTop, Char sourceChar, ConsoleColor sourceForeColor, ConsoleColor sourceBackColor)
   at System.Console.MoveBufferArea(Int32 sourceLeft, Int32 sourceTop, Int32 sourceWidth, Int32 sourceHeight, Int32 targetLeft, Int32 targetTop)
```

I've managed to get my library to work around everything except the MoveBufferArea method, and almost have a nice hack work around using `Virtual-terminal-sequences`, hence this SO question.

...when running on Mac in a terminal window, I can scroll a (100% wide) region of the window, by setting the Scrolling Region using [**terminal-sequences**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/console-virtual-terminal-sequences#viewport-positioning), but can only set the top and bottom margin, using `virtual-terminal-sequences.`

from : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/console-virtual-terminal-sequences#viewport-positioning

So, using terminal sequences I can set the Top and Bottom margin, then I can call scroll, then I reset the scroll regions and return to my library for all other window writing.

The problem is (as per the title) that I can not find any way to set the left and right margin, which means I cannot scroll a neat (startx, startY, width, height) portion of the screen, I am forced to scroll the whole width.

This feels SOOO close. if I can find a hack to tell a Mac (Nix) window to please scroll a region of a console window, or, I can set the Left and Right margin before calling scrollup, or ScrollDown, then that would also solve me my problem and my Konsole library would be fully cross platform.

This can apparently be done using something called `ncurses` but all the documentation I have found for that appear to require that you do some wierd mind meld compile time magic to get them to work.

Any help would be amazing and super super appreciated!

here's some code that shows how the terminal sequences are used

```cs
        private static void SetScrollMargins(int top, int bottom) => Console.Write("\x1b[" + top + ";" + bottom + "r");
        private static void ScrollUp() => Console.Write("\x1b[1S");
        private static void ScrollDown() => Console.Write("\x1b[1T");

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            try
            {
            Console.Clear();

            // fill the screen with random stuff so that we can see
            // that a small portion (region) of the screen is moved up and down
            // with each call to scroll up/down without the rest of the screen 
            // being impacted. Demonstrates that all I am missing is left and right margins
            // and my problem is solved. Sooo close, but sooo far!

            for (int i = 0; i < 800; i++) Console.Write($" ({i} ) ");
            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.WriteLine("set scrollmargins, press a key");
            Console.ReadKey(true);
            SetScrollMargins(2, 5);
            for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
            {

                Console.ReadKey(true);
                ScrollUp();
                Console.ReadKey(true);
                ScrollDown();
            }
        }
```

So ideally I'm hoping I've missed an obvious trick where you can in fact set the left and right margin, using terminal-sequences, or via some other terminal sequence code that Mac Terminals support.

Thanks to everyone in advance. Happy new year too :D

update:

I managed to find some tests that hint at the functionality being plausible. e.g. `DECLRMM` (https://vt100.net/docs/vt510-rm/DECLRMM.html)

[This Java test for example](https://www.codota.com/code/java/methods/com.termux.terminal.ScrollRegionTest/withTerminalSized)

```java
public void testScrollRegionRight() {
  // ${CSI}?69h for DECLRMM enabling, ${CSI}${LEFTMARGIN};${RIGHTMARGIN}s for DECSLRM margin setting.
  withTerminalSized(3, 3).enterString("YYY\033[?69h\033[1;2sABCDEF").assertLinesAre("ABY", "CD ", "EF ");
  enterString("GH").assertLinesAre("CDY", "EF ", "GH ").enterString("IJ").assertLinesAre("EFY", "GH ", "IJ ");
  enterString("\n").assertLinesAre("GHY", "IJ ", "   ");
}
```

I've tried this, but can't get this to work, seems to be ignored, and possibly this open happens with `terminal.app` on Mac, as  @Thomas Dickey has suggested in the comments.

Comment: Some terminals support left/right margins; MacOS Terminal.app is not one of those.

Comment: This isn't about setting the margin of the terminal itself, this is about the ScrollMargin, so that when you call scroll, the margin is taken into account. I'm hoping there is a simple way to achieve this.

Comment: Update: further to what Thomas Dickey suggests I managed to find this document that suggests only xterm (out of the terminals that this document covers) implements  DECSLRM. 

https://terminalguide.netlify.com/seq/
This isn't definitive, and Terminal.app is not among the list of apps. @ThomasDickey if you can provide a definitive reference showing that the terminal does not support this? ... then that could also be a place I could watch for updates. That would be appreciated It seems like a much requested feature necessary to prevent excessive CPU/bandwith with consoles "emulating" windows.

Comment: [vttest](https://invisible-island.net/vttest/vttest.html) has tests for the feature (menu 11.3.6, "VT420 Rectangular Area Tests").  The link you indicate is missing a lot of information, and some is incorrect (I mentioned that to the author in 2018).

Comment: pluse-uno for the most interesting and well documented question of the year, so far ;-) . (Ha, and I couldn't remember the exact `VT` terminal that multi-windowed anymore, VT420 it is!). Good luck!